# R - Extract Regex groups

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, extract

I am working with a data frame `df` with a column `text` which contains strings of either the form `"WORD"` or `"WORD, WORD2"`. More precisely, there may be some gibberish before or after these blocks, but I know how to take care of them.

I would like to use the tidyverse function `extract` to obtain extract the two words into two columns `t1` and `t2` such that the string `"WORD"` gets extracted into the `"WORD"` and `NA` and

- the string `"WORDS"` gets extracted into `"WORDS"` and `Na`,
- the string `"WORDS, WORD2"` gets extracted into `"WORDS"` and `"WORD2"`.

I tried a command of the following form

```
df |> extract(x, c("1", "2"), "([^[:punct:]]+),?[[:space:]]?([^[:punct:]]*)",
              remove = FALSE,
              convert = TRUE)
```

However, this always reads the first row into `"WORD"` and `""` (empty string). How can I modify my version to obtain the desired behaviour?

**EDIT:** Here is a possible dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c("123 WORD", "4564 WORD, TEST 1"))

# Expected output
df_out <- data.frame(x = c("123 WORD", "4564 WORD, TEST 1"),
                     t1 = c("WORD", "WORD"),
                     t2 = c(NA, "TEST"))
```

Comment: You need to provide data for us to work on

Comment: @Onyambu I included a more explicit example in my latest edit.

Comment: there are many ways, not sure if there is an argument in `extract` to do it, for example `type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE, na.strings = '')`

Comment: `separate(df, x, c('t1', 't2'), fill = 'right')` works for you?

Comment: @Onyambu Unfortunately, this doesn't work because of the gibberish I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Thats why we asked for a data to work on that resembles your data. If you give something that does not depic your data you will get incorrect answers. The answe I posted in the previous comment does indeed resolve the issue with the data provide

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry, that understand that this is frustrating. I've updated the example data.

Comment: You might have missed. I believe row 1 should be WORD, NA and row 2 should be WORD, TEST

Comment: There is no `TEST` in your df. Also is the word gonna be `WORD`?

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
  extract(x, c('t1','t2'), '(\\w+)(?:, (\\w+).*)?$', FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(c(t1, t2), na_if, ''))

                  x   t1   t2
1          123 WORD WORD <NA>
2 4564 WORD, TEST 1 WORD TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("123 WORD", "4564 WORD, TEST 1"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(x1 = str_remove_all(x, '[0-9]*')) %>% 
  separate(x1, c("t1", "t2"), sep = ', ', remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(-x1)
```

```
                  x    t1    t2
1          123 WORD  WORD  <NA>
2 4564 WORD, TEST 1  WORD TEST
```